# Disabled button when mat-radio is not selected

Tags: angular, typescript, forms, button, radio-button

I have a form of `mat-radio-group` and a `button`:

```
<form action="">
    <mat-radio-group aria-label="Select an option">
    <mat-radio-button value="1">Option 1</mat-radio-button>
    <mat-radio-button value="2">Option 2</mat-radio-button>
    </mat-radio-group>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

I want to disabled `button` when `mat-radio` is not selected

Comment: Declare `formControl` for your radio buttons and use the `required validator` for them. Place conditional statement for submit button e.g. `[disabled]="form.invalid"`.

Answer (score 0):

It might help:

```
<md-radio-group [(ngModel)]="isSelected">
    <md-radio-button *ngFor="let key of array" [value]="key" (change)="radioChange($event)">
        {{key}}
    </md-radio-button>
</md-radio-group>
```

In your .ts file:

```
radioChange(event: MdRadioChange) {
    this.isSubmitButtonEnabled = event.value; //It returns a boolean value.
}
```

After detecting the value changes of your radio button, apply these classes on the button as per your requirement.

```
[class.opacity-50]="!isSubmitButtonEnabled" [disabled]="!isSubmitButtonEnabled"
```